# Ajax in rails for a nested resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have these pahts in my website:

```
/stops/13090
/stops/13090/services
```

so in `config.rb` I have:

```
resources :stops do
  resources :services, only: [:index]
end
```

When the user navigates to `/stops/13090`, I would like to show a webpage that includes both the data for `/stops/13090` rendered by the `StopsController` and the data for `/stops/13090/services` rendered by the `ServicesController`. So I'd like it to **initiate two HTTP requests**: one to `/stops/13090` and one to `/stops/13090/services`, and combine both in the web page.

I've tried googling various terms, but I'm not sure what exactly I should search for to solve this. I've tried using `render partial:` but it seems unrelated to ajax.

I prefer HAML, but it's perfectly fine if the answers are for a different template engine.

Comment: basically, you are displaying a 'stop' object with its 'services'. since you will be landing on the show page of 'stop', you can collect the services by @stop.services and display them. you dont need an ajax.

Comment: I do need ajax because I want this to happen asynchronously. The `/stops/13090/services` request might take a long time, and I want to display the stop details to the user without waiting for the services to return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send a ajax request when a particular element in the page has been loaded.

```
$( "#result" ).load(some_url_path, function() {
  return $.ajax({
    url: "/stop/" + stop_id + "services"
  });
});
```

and in the services.js.haml, you can load the services collection on the 'stop' show page. checkout https://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: Thank you. Where do I put this code? I have a template for the show action of the stop, what should I do next?

Comment: @IlyaKogan you should add the code in the file from where you want to send the ajax request. In the current scenario, this should be 'show' page for stop object.

Comment: I'm struggling with getting this to work (what is `some_url_path`?), but the following code works great once added to the end of the HAML template: 
`:javascript`
`$("#services").load('/stops/#{@stop.stop_id}/services');`. I also had do specify `%div{:id => 'services'}`.

Comment: its great that the code you submitted works. You will need an id/class in the show.html.haml which will be replaced by the 'index' partial. also, since u are using haml, u dont need to specify the div explicitly. just add a class or id and haml will place it as an attribute of a div.